# C# Inheritance: Static vs. Non-Static Field

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I have a library base class (`Controller`) and three sub-classes that inherit from `Controller` (`Sensor`, `Output`, and `Environment`) where:

```
public class Controller
{
   private SerialPort serial;
   private Sensor sensorSettings;
   private Output outputSettings;
   private Environment environmentSettings;       


   protected Dictionary<int, string> ErrorDescriptions
   { get{ this.errorDescriptions; } }

   protected SerialPort ControllerSerialPort
   { get{ this.serial; } }

   protected Sensor SensorSettings
   { get{ this.sensorSettings; } }

   // The other sub-class get properties.

   protected string SendReceive(string controllerCommand)
   { ... }

   ...
 }

 public class Sensor : Controller {...}
 ... // Other sub-classes
```

My question is this: Should I make the `errorDescriptions` static? These error descriptions will not change from controller to controller (i.e. static) but I wasn't sure what happens in the inherited classes. Will I have to refer to them as `Sensor.errorDescription` in the `Sensor` class or will it still be `Controller.errorDescription`?

**EDIT**

Wow, I just realized I messed up big time. Here's how it should be, I think:

```
private abstract class ControllerBasics
{
   protected SerialPort serial;  // The serial port to communicate with the controller.
   protected Dictionary<int, string> errorDescriptions = new Dictionary<int, string> {...};   // Possible errors for the controller (known and fixed). Won't change from controller to controller.
   public enum Sensors {One, Two, ...};   // Possible sensor selection.

   public string SendReceiveCommand(string command){...} // Method to send string command over "serial".       
}

public class OverallController : ControllerBasics // The controller class.
{       
   // Add top-level controller settings.
   private string controllerName = "Controller1"; // Have a property to get/set.
   private bool controllerON; // Controller on/off. Have property to get/set.
   ... // Other similar fields and methods.

   // Used to "sort" the controller's many settings/functions.
   private SensorSettings sensorSettings;  // Have get/set properties for these so I could do the following: overallControllerInstance.GetSensorSettingsProperty.SetActiveSensorCount(5);
   private OutputSettings outputSettings;
   private EnvironmentSettings environmentSettings;

   public OverallController(string name, string comPort, ...)  // Constructor.
   {
      // Basic settings initialization.
      // Create serial port.
      this.sensorSettings = new SensorSettings(this.serial);
      this.outputSettings = ...
}

public class SensorSettings : ControllerBasics // Class to hold the controller's specific sensor settings and their respective get/set methods. Not a new type of controller.
{
   private int activeSensorCount; // Have public method to get/set.
   ... // Others.

  public void SetActiveSensorCount(int sensorCount)
  {
     // Send command using inherited SendReceive().
  }
  ... // Others.
}

public class OutputSettings : ControllerBasics   // Same logic as SensorSettings.
{
   private string units; // Have public method to get/set.
   ... // Others.

  public string GetUnitType()  // Meters, mm, um...
  {
     // Send command using inherited SendReceive().
  }
  ... // Others.
}

public class EnvironmentSettings : ControllerBasics   // Same logic as SensorSettings.
{
   ...
}
```

So if `errorDescriptions` defined in `ControllerBasics` is known and fixed (and required in all derived classes) should I make it static or should I just leave it protected and each derived class will have it's own dictionary (i.e. this.errorDescriptions)?

Comment: If you are planning to do this, don't access the dictionary directly, but rather add some static methods which will use a static lock, to ensure thread safety.

Comment: @Groo, true, but locking will only be necessary if the dictionary isn't fully populated in the base static initializer.  (and it sounds like it could be)

Comment: @Jon, your question is unlikely to solicit a good new response at this point.  Since you wrote the question wrong the first time, I recommend you submit a new question written how you intend, nothing wrong with that.  You may even want to undo your edits on this question and just leave it for your new question.  (I'm just trying to help you have your question legitimately reach more eyeballs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would only be *one* static variable, however many subclasses you have. Is it meant to vary by subclass, or is it *truly* one global mapping? If it's the latter, then a static variable is appropriate. If not... well, there are various options, but you'd need to tell us what you're using the map for.

Comment: I updated the original post, I had it completely wrong before. There is only one controller so I used inheritance to basically share the controller's serial port and other, very basic methods/fields that are required by all of the controller's serial commands. I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Well, a private member won't be visible to your derived classes. You would need a protected member or property for that. Within the class, you can just refer to it as errorDescriptions or this.errorDescriptions.

I'd be extremely wary of having a static, protected member variable that isn't thread safe  and can be mutated by derived classes. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Unless you synchronize them, yes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx and scroll to the "Thread Safety" section. You're safe if you only have multiple readers, but for multiple readers and writers, you'll either need to synchronize or use a ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: Right, you're safe unless you have multiple writers, so the statement "only public static Dictionaries are thread safe" is confusing at best.  Since 1) being "public" is irrelevent 2) being "static" is irrelevent 3) It's not thread safe if you write to it

Comment: Ah, right. I misread "members" as "instances". I will correct the mind fart.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one instance of the dictionary than yes, change it to protected static. Also you should use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead for thread safety.

In the derived classes you access the field using `Controller.errorDescription`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I updated my original post (I got it pretty wrong the first time around) and now it is in an abstract class. Would that make any difference?

Comment: Well do you want every instance of controller to share the same dictionary? We cant answer that. But if you do you should use the ConcurrentDictionary instead as it is thread safe.