# C# Inheritance: Use static field?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, static-members

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Inheritance: Static vs. Non-Static Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732723/c-inheritance-static-vs-non-static-field)

I am working on creating a class library for a control circuit:

```
private abstract class ControllerBasics
{
   protected SerialPort serial;  // The serial port to communicate with the controller.
   protected Dictionary<int, string> errorDescriptions = new Dictionary<int, string> {{1, "Sensor Error"},{2, "Controller Error"}, ...};   // Possible errors for the controller (known and fixed). Won't change from controller to controller.

   public string SendReceiveCommand(string command){...} // Method to send string command over "serial".       
}

public class OverallController : ControllerBasics // The actual class used to communicate with the controller.
{       
   // Add top-level controller settings.
   private string controllerName = "Controller1"; // Have a property to get/set.
   private bool controllerON; // Controller on/off. Have property to get/set.
   ... // Other similar fields and methods.

   // Used to "sort" the controller's many settings/functions.
   private SensorSettings sensorSettings;  // Have get/set properties for these so I could do the following: overallControllerInstance.GetSensorSettingsProperty.SetActiveSensorCount(5);
   private OutputSettings outputSettings;
   private EnvironmentSettings environmentSettings;

   public OverallController(string name, string comPort, ...)  // Constructor.
   {
      // Basic settings initialization.
      // Create serial port.
      this.sensorSettings = new SensorSettings(this.serial);
      this.outputSettings = ...
}

public class SensorSettings : ControllerBasics // Class to hold the controller's specific sensor settings and their respective get/set methods. Not a new type of controller.
{
   private int activeSensorCount; // Have public method to get/set.
   ... // Others.

  public void SetActiveSensorCount(int sensorCount)
  {
     // Send command using inherited SendReceive().
  }
  ... // Others.
}

public class OutputSettings : ControllerBasics   // Same logic as SensorSettings.
{
   private string units; // Have public method to get/set.
   ... // Others.

  public string GetUnitType()  // Meters, mm, um...
  {
     // Send command using inherited SendReceive().
  }
  ... // Others.
}

public class EnvironmentSettings : ControllerBasics   // Same logic as SensorSettings.
{
   ...
}
```

So if `errorDescriptions` defined in `ControllerBasics` is known and fixed at compile time should I make it static or should I just leave it protected and each derived class will have it's own dictionary (i.e. this.errorDescriptions)? If I make it static, how would I reference it in a derived class? For example, if in `Sensor Settings` would I use `ControllerBasics.errorDescriptions` or `SensorSettings.errorDescriptions`?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at most questions that are new they are most likely a rehash of a previous question. People usually don't search for their question before they post.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the static approach, it's more logic, faster and memory efficient.
And Yes, you could use ControllerBasics.errorDescriptions or SensorSettings.errorDescriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Both. If the error messages are known at compile time you're probably best off combining the two - make it `protected static Dictionary<int, string> errorDescriptions`

and then you can use either class name or this.errorDescriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the errors are, at least for now, constant, I see nothing wrong with having them static and shared amongst all instances. Depending on use, it could introduce a code smell, but it is easy enough to refactor the smell out.

On the other side of the equation, I would ask how often you actually use the error messages and whether or not storing them outside the actual class might be a better solution. In addition, would it be better to make your own exception classes so one consuming your library could determine the type of failure without searching strings.

Just thoughts.